# AWS WAF Client-side certificate Authentication

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, amazon-waf

The client-side certificates are authenticated on my EC2 machine running a web application that is in a public subnet behind AWS WAF.

My question is, will AWS WAF alter or tamper with the client-side certificate in the request? Will it have an effect on the desired end result?

Answer (score 0):

Contacted Amazon support to get my question answered, if you’re looking for the answer: AWS WAF does not tamper with the client side certificate.